# Expressing long chain of compositions in Haskell

Tags: haskell, coding-style, function-composition

(unimportant background info / motivation)

I was implementing a different version of `nub`, inspired by the [Yesod book's discouragement](http://www.yesodweb.com/book/widgets) of using it.

> `map head . group . sort` is more efficient than a call to `nub`. However, in our case, order is important...

So I set out writing a "better" nub akin to the order-unimportant version. And I ended up with this:

```
mynub = unsort . map head . groupBy (\x y -> fst x == fst y) . sortBy (comparing fst) . rememberPosition

rememberPosition = flip zip [0..]
unsort = map fst . sortBy (comparing snd)
```

This certainly does a lot of extra work, but it should be O(n log n) instead of original nub's O(n<sup>2</sup>). But that's beside the point. The problem is, *it's so long*! It's really not that complicated, but it's long (and I'm one of those people that hates going wider than 80 columns, or horizontal scrollbars on StackOverflow code blocks).

(the question)

**What are better ways in Haskell for expressing long chains of function composition such as this?**

Comment: Three important things to note.  `nub` just has an `Eq a` constraint, and your version has an `Ord a` constraint.  `nub` works on infinite lists, your version doesn't.  Also, `nub`'s worst-case may be worse than your code, but its best case is better than your code.  The most significant difference is the `Ord a` constraint.  If you allow that, you can write something more complicated that is O(n log n) worst-case, almost as good as `nub` in the best case, and works on infinite lists.  But it involves non-list data structures.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Break up the line, and use the layout:

```
mynub = unsort 
      . map head 
      . groupBy ((==) `on` fst)
      . sortBy (comparing fst) 
      . rememberPosition
```

Answer (score 8):

line width is easily solved :)

```
> mynub = { unsort 
>         . map head 
>         . groupBy (\x y -> fst x == fst y) 
>         . sortBy (comparing fst) 
>         . rememberPosition
>         }
```

but I'm barely used to reading composition right to left. Top to bottom is a bit much.
Arrow or (>>>)=flip (.) looks nicer to me, but I have no idea if it would be idiomatic

```
> mynub = { rememberPosition
>       >>> sortBy (comparing fst) 
>       >>> groupBy (\x y -> fst x == fst y) 
>       >>> map head 
>       >>> unsort 
>         }
```

Comment: `(>>>)` is somewhat unidiomatic, but is defined in the `base` library: http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Control-Category.html#v:-62--62--62-